# JavaFX Concurrency: How to updateMessage() to the controller with interface?

Tags: javafx, concurrency, controller, bind

Before I learned about running tasks on the background thread I learned how to post messages to my UI via my controller with an Interface. The interface allows me to have a systems messages in any controller. but I cant figure out how to bind it to updateMessage from a task.

My interface:

```
public interface SystemMessage {
    void postMessage(String outText);
}
```

My controller:

```
public class MainController implements SystemMessage {
    @FXML
    public DialogPane systemMessage;

    @Override
    public void postMessage(String outText) {
        systemMessage.setContentText(outText);
   }

   //***I have tried the following to bind the dialog pane to the updateMessage

   systemMessage.contentTextProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());

   //***InteliJ tells me that it can not resolve contetTextProperty or task.
}
```

My Main class with the Task on a new thread.

```
private SystemMessage mainController;

FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/entry.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
this.mainController = (SystemMessage) loader.getController();

api = new Api();
machineId = new Identity();
    db = new SqLite();
    //mainController.postMessage(task.messageProperty()).bind();
    Thread th = new Thread(task);
    th.setDaemon(true);
    th.start();

Task<String> task = new Task<String>() {
    @Override protected String call() throws Exception {
        checkAsiServer();
        updateMessage("API Checked.");

        checkMachineId();
        updateMessage("Machine Id Checked.");

        checkDb();
        updateMessage("Server Checked.");

        return "done";
    }
};
```

I have tried to bind my DialogPane in the cotroller by:

```
systemMessage.contentTextProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());
```

**But it can not resolve contentTextProperty and I don't know how to tell the controller about the task object either.**

Comment: I'm confused where the last code block is from? This is inside the controller? If so, I don't see what the problem is.

Comment: @James_D no the last code block is in Main which is also where the task is running. You helped me figure out the Task component! Incedentally I can make this work with a RunLater(), but I am thinking that updateMessage to my interface would be more.... elegant??

Comment: @James_D.. If you were referring to systemMessage... code block that is in the controller. but it can not resolve contentTextProprty or task.

Comment: But `systemMessage` is not defined in `Main`, it's defined in your controller. I think you need to post a [MCVE]. This seems to have nothing at all to do with concurrency or multithreading, it's just regular Java/OOP and calling methods, etc.

Comment: @James_D Sorry, I did not post the TASK!!! SEE UPdate. I am trying to populate a DialogPane from a running task on a seperate thread from the UI. SystemMessage is an interface implemented by the controller. I get a reference to the mainController in the Main Class.

Comment: `contentTextProperty()` is a method defined in `DialogPane`, and you have defined `DialogPane systemMessage;` in your controller, not in the `Main` class. I have no idea what the `SystemMessage` interface is, but apparently it doesn't have a `contextTextProperty()` method. You can't magically make something into a different type by giving it the same variable name as something in a completely different class. Post a [MCVE].

Comment: Why are you creating the `Task` in the `Main` class in the first place? Why not create it in the controller?

Comment: Well I thought that since the task was performing background updates that have nothing to do with the UI it should remain in the Main Class. I thought the controller was just to handle the UI.

Comment: The main class really should do nothing except start the application. If you want to separate out the creation of the task, etc, put that in another class entirely. (It is more "model" than "controller".) But I still don't get the problem, really.

Comment: I see. The problem is that I can not get the DialogPane in the controller to bind to the Tasks UpdateMessage: examples that i see are like: myTextArea.textProperty().bind(myController.myService.messageProperty());

Comment: Why don't you just expose the strong property you want to bind from the controller?

Comment: I don't know how. But I guess I can look up what it is to expose something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand the problem. Why don't you just expose the property from the controller? You can do

```
public class MainController implements SystemMessage {
    @FXML
    private DialogPane systemMessage;

    public StringProperty messageProperty() {
        return systemMessage.contentTextProperty();
    }

    // ...
}
```

and then

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/entry.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
MainController mainController = loader.getController();

Task<String> task = new Task<String>() { /* existing code... */};

mainController.messageProperty().bind(task.messageProperty());

Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

If you want to keep the type of the controller as `SystemMessage` and only rely on the `postMessage` method, then obviously you can't do this with a binding (because you don't have any way to access the property); you would need to use a listener instead:

```
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml/entry.fxml"));
Parent root = loader.load();
SystemMessage mainController = loader.getController();

Task<String> task = new Task<String>() { /* existing code... */};

task.messageProperty().addListener((obs, oldMessage, newMessage) ->
    mainController.postMessage(newMessage));    

Thread thread = new Thread(task);
thread.setDaemon(true);
thread.start();
```

Comment: When I try the first solution InteliJ says messageProperty can not be resolved.

Comment: @silversunhunter You did everything I suggested? Added the `messageProperty()` method to the controller and changed the type of `mainController` to `MainController`?

Comment: Ahh. sorry, I did not change the type back to MainController. I have now done that and I removed the interface all together. I am getting an InvocationException caused by a NullPointerException at the return statement for the stringProperty we created.

Comment: When I tried your second solution i got a null pointer exception as well in that their was no string for postMessage.

Comment: @silversunhunter That is something completely different. It means `systemMessage`
 is null in the controller, which means you haven't connected the FXML element correctly. That's an entirely different question.

Comment: You are right. Somehow systemMessage was null. All I did is remove the interface from the controller. After I changed the ID in the FXML and the Controller it worked.Thanks for sticking with me on this. If I could i'd buy you a few beers, or Ice tea if you don't drink that stuff :-).. I think i learned a few things here.